# How can I make this timepicker using jquery or if available please suggest

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to make timepicker like this

[image]

I have gone through jQuery time picker but it doesn't provides UI for picking AM/PM.

```
$('input.timepicker').timepicker();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wvega/Cas6T/embedded/result,js,html,css,resources/

Can anyone suggest how can I make AM/PM selection control.

Comment: Please consider reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've edited question, is their any solution or do i need to make new component for this

Answer (score 1):

If you want this type of format, try this code hope useful -

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
         timeFormat: 'h:mm',
        });
        
        $('#btnClick').on('click',function(){
        if($('.timepicker').val().trim()=="")
        alert('Seelct the time plz')
        else
         alert($('.timepicker').val()+' '+$('#format').val())
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
    background: #EFEFEF;
    padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>jQuery TimePicker Demo</h1>

<br/>

<link src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css' type='text/css'/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js'></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="time"/><select id='format'>
    <option value='AM'>AM</option>
    <option value='PM'>PM</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type='button' value='Click Here' id='btnClick'>
</form>
```